# Loading native libraries in Quarkus only once in dev mode

Tags: java, quarkus

I have a jni library in my project. I have no problem with loading it in the project on start up of quarkus, but when I change something in the code, it triggers hot reload and tries to load the same library again.

```
@Startup
public class StartUpService {

    void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {
        try {
            loadCoreLibrary();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.error("Couldn't load libraries ", ex);
            Quarkus.asyncExit();
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to load it only once or it's better not to use hot reload for dev purposes in my case?